# Russels's Paradox: Well-defined collection of well-defined objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory, paradoxes

The standard definition of a set is well-defined collection of objects. Here I assume that well-defined collection would mean any object is either a member of the collection or not.

But if we take the definition of set to be well-defined collection of "well-defined" objects then can we overcome the Russell's paradox ? I'm just asking this from a naive beginners perspective.

For the collection $A$ of objects which are not members of themselves is not even a "well-defined" object in the first place. Because if $A$ itself is in the collection then it is not and the vice versa. I'm aware that this collection is considered a proper class in modern set theory.

Comment: "For the collection $A$ of sets which are not members of themselves is not even a "well-defined" object in the first place..." It sounds like you are excluding $A$ from contention *because* it is subject to a paradox. Of course, if you define "well-definedness" to basically exclude all paradoxes discovered, past and future, then your naive theory of sets will be paradox-free! But good luck finding *anything* that you can be certain actually is a well-defined set! How would you know that there are no undiscovered paradoxes out there that would apply to a given set?

Comment: ZF set theory defines sets in a way that contradicitons arriving from self reference are not possible

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Contributions_to_the_Founding_of_the_The/aagYb7FgeAMC) page 85 for Cantor's original concept of set. And see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221988/how-exactly-do-we-explain-distinct-objects-in-the-definition-of-set).

Comment: The two basic ideas are: (i) that of "collecting into a whole" (*Zusammenfassung*) that means to "create" in our mind a single object for which we can meaningfully "predicate" something (i.e. expressing its properties).

Comment: And (ii) that of definite and separate objects of our intuition or our thought, that means e.g. numbers and not "feeling".

Comment: Ok, but these definite and separate objects have to be well-defined first.

Comment: Naive understanding, well-defined = no paradoxes

Comment: Basically we start form a *domain* of objects that we know (in the naive sense), like e.g. numbers. If the objects that we want to "collect into a whole" are finite in number, then we can list them, and this is enough to form the "collection", *class* or *set* which Cantor is speaking. But if they are not finite in number, we need a "property" to identify which objects of the domain will form the collection. We have to use a "description" or mathematical formula that applies to the objects of the domain, like e.g "to be even". In this way, we will select all even numbers from the domain.

Comment: See also the answer to [What is the real being(entity?) the word set or class denotes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232633/what-is-the-real-beingentity-the-word-set-or-class-denotes) as well as that to [What is the meaning of "perceiving all sets"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695338/what-is-the-meaning-of-perceiving-all-sets)

Comment: Your intuition is on an interesting path. Godel did something similar while studying definability. He developed the Constructable Universe, a Set Theoretic Universe where every set is "definable" that is there is a formula which can determine what is in the set or not in the set.

Comment: @MichaelCarey It's not true that in the constructible universe every set is definable (or not necessarily true, or nonsensical, depending on how we think about the terms. )

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you're right, it's more complicated than what I wrote, my intention was a more "gist of it" kind of answer. I should have made reference to the definable Powerset, and how in L, every set is constructable, whether they are also definable, is as you said, more complicated.